# Check if a row exists in database and if not display a message

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't manage to check if a row exists in database and if not display a message. The code is below. I need a little help.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT client_cv FROM formular_client WHERE id = '$id'"); 
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
       echo "<a href='../cv/" . $rows['client_cv'] . "' target='_blank' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> Descarca CV</a>";
   } else {
       echo "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'><span  class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> Fara CV</a>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Do you know where it exactly fails. Is it the query or is it the echo's or some other error? Usually an `id` is an integer which means you don't wrap it in quotes. So maybe you could try: `id = $id`

Comment: code if correct, i think there is no row in ur db.

Comment: Ok, so what i have to do is if there is info in the client_cv row then show the button else show another button. The problem is that if i have or i don't have anu info in that row shows me the same button, the first one to be exactly but without the " . $rows['client_cv'] . " part.

Comment: is there a row in db for that id currently??

Comment: I must correct it is not a row it is a field..

Comment: Yes. I have an id for that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show different links based on if `client_cv` has a value or not, try this

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT client_cv FROM formular_client WHERE id = '$id'"); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (strlen($rows["client_cv"]) > 0){
            echo "<a href='../cv/" . $rows['client_cv'] . "' target='_blank' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> Descarca CV</a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'><span  class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> Fara CV</a>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No record found"
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\formular\administrare\client.php on line 166